# PhysicallyBasedMaterial always render specular/shine

Tags: arkit, fragment-shader, realitykit

I'm messing around with RealityKit's new custom material to write my own fragment/surface shader. Everything's okay and I can finally write my own shader to render my procedural vfx on a simple plane like this :

[image]

Everything looks good until I move my camera around and apparently if my custom material is based on PhysicallyBasedMaterial it renders the specular/shiny part of the object regardless what I set on my surface shader

This is what it looks like given a certain angle :

[image]

I've been playing around with roughness and metallic settings both on the material properties and through the surface shader itself but nothing removes this specular rendering.

Anyone can help me? Thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

Are you setting the specular parameter in your shader, like you are with the metallic and roughness parameters?

According to [Altering RealityKit Rendering with Shader Functions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/altering_realitykit_rendering_with_shader_functions):

> A custom material’s surface shader is responsible for setting all of
> the rendering attributes of the current fragment.

Then, in reference to PhysicallyBasedMaterial:

> In order to replicate that behavior, the shader has to set all of the
> properties used by PhysicallyBasedMaterial to ensure that RealityKit
> renders the model correctly.

I believe you can try `set_specular` and
`set_clearcoat` in your shader to quickly see if this is the right way to go.

```
params.surface().set_surface(0.0);
params.surface().set_clearcoat(0.0);
```

If so, I suggest taking a look at the sample code to see how Apple are using the `(...)PassThrough(params);` functions  to "pass-through" the material parameters you set in RealityKit — or taking an even deeper look into the [Metal RealityKit API](https://developer.apple.com/metal/Metal-RealityKit-APIs.pdf#page55)

Answer (score 0):

I found a sort of working solution in  the ambient occlusion value.

Based on what the doc says :

*Ambient occlusion represents the entity’s exposure to ambient light. A value of black (0.0), the
darkest pixel value in a grayscale image, represents parts of the model that receive no ambient
light because they may be crevices, dents, or recessed areas, or another part of the same entity
prevents ambient light from reaching it. Ambient occlusion values of white (1.0), the lightest
pixel value, represent flat portions of the model that receive full ambient light.*

I figure well at least for any transparent surface it shouldn't receive any lighting which after I change the ambient occlusion value to match the opacity then I get the result I wanted.

Not sure if this is the right way to do it though?

Answer (score 0):

customMaterial = CustomMaterial(surfaceShader: surfaceShader2, lightingModel: .clearcoat) or.unlit for your case

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).